# Datagridview email if specific columns contains certain text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, datagridview

I have a data that populates in datagridview after my search is complete. I can email the listed people. I want to add a statement to check column 25 for specific text ("1"), if it finds it then add this recipient.

Thank you for any help!

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
            outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[25].Value != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[25].Value.ToString().Contains("1"))
                    {
                        mailItem.To = "test@test.com";
                    }                                            
                }
            }
            mailItem.To = string.Join(";", c1.Union(c2).Union(c3).Union(c4).ToArray());  

        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred trying to Create an Outlook Email"
                                + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
  for(int i =0 ;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[25].Value != null)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[25].Value.ToString().Contains("1"))
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried that and i got a catch error...Ill update the code so you can see it.

Comment: I just updated the code at the very top..it was too long to enter in the comment.

Comment: At the cath.... catch (Exception eX)
            {
                throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred trying to Create an Outlook Email"
                                    + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
            }

Comment: I mean when the debugger go to catch? Which line produces the exception? Did the exception happens in the loop or int the mailTo?

Comment: Aww gotcha..sry still a rookie to this. It happened in the Loop.